# Python OAuth WooCommerce

Tags: python, api, http, post, woocommerce

I am trying to use a WooCommerce Python client to make a POST request but
I get "Provided Signature does not match"

The client I use is from:

[WooCommerce API OAuth in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260072/woocommerce-api-oauth-in-python)

This is my client:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
import random
import string
import time
from hashlib import sha1
import hmac
import binascii
import re
import collections
from urllib import quote, urlencode


def uksort(dictionary):
    return collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dictionary.items(), cmp = cmp))

class WooCommerce(object):
    def __init__(self, consumer_key, consumer_secret, endpoint):

        self.consumer_key = consumer_key
        self.consumer_secret = consumer_secret
        self.endpoint = endpoint

    def _make_request(self, resource, params, method = "GET"):
        oauth_params = {
            "oauth_consumer_key": self.consumer_key,
            "oauth_nonce": self._gen_nonce(),
            "oauth_timestamp": self._gen_timestamp(),
            "oauth_signature_method": "HMAC-SHA1",
        }

        oauth_params["oauth_signature"] = self._gen_signature(resource, dict(params.items() + oauth_params.items()), method)
        params = dict(params.items() + oauth_params.items())

        if method == "GET":
            print self.endpoint + resource + "?" + urlencode(params)
        elif method == "POST":
            print self.endpoint + resource + "?" + urlencode(params)
            req = urllib.request.Request(self.endpoint + resource + "?" + urlencode(params))
            open = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
            requestContent = open.read()
            #print(open)

    def _gen_nonce(self):

        ran_string = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for i in range(32)).encode("base64")
        alnum_hash = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', "", ran_string)
        return alnum_hash

    def _gen_timestamp(self):

        return int(time.time())

    def _gen_signature(self, resource, params, method):

        base_request_uri = quote(self.endpoint + resource, safe = "")
        normalized_params = self._normalize_params(params)
        sorted_params = uksort(normalized_params)
        query_string = "%26".join([key + "%3D" + value for key, value in sorted_params.iteritems()])

        raw_string = method + "&" + base_request_uri + "&" + query_string
        hashed = hmac.new(self.consumer_secret, raw_string, sha1)

        return binascii.b2a_base64(hashed.digest()).rstrip("\n")

    def _normalize_params(self, params):

        normalized = {}

        for key, value in params.iteritems():
            key = quote(str(key), safe = "")
            value = quote(str(value), safe = "")

            normalized[key] = value

        return normalized
```

And I use it like this from another class:

```
woo_client = WooCommerce('ck_7bb1951bee7454b2e29bf5eef9205e0e', 'cs_155cd9420201c0a7e140bebd6a9794c7', 'http://dima.bg/wc-api/v2')

data = {
               "product": {
                "title": "testname",
               }
           }    
result = self.woo_client._make_request("/products/", data, 'POST')
```

Can you see something wrong with my URL ? Thanks for your time.

http://xxxxxxxxx.xx/wc-api/v2/products/?product=%7B%27title%27%3A+%27testname%27%7D&oauth_nonce=NThWODczRFIyWkxRNFZOVkUxNFdRSVo0QjFSNllIVFk&oauth_timestamp=1423647865&oauth_consumer_key=ck_7bb1951bee7454b2e29bf5eef9205e0e&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature=3PSnEEf08gFthIRAr8AUKQiDjco%3D

Answer (score 0):

I used your code as a starting point for my own solution to this problem and had some success! Here's what I did:

```
import requests
import random
import string
import time
from hashlib import sha1
import hmac
import binascii
import re
from urllib import quote, urlencode
import httplib2
from collections import OrderedDict

def key_compare(a, b):
    return cmp(a[0], b[0])

class Restful_Client(object):
    """docstring for Restful_Client"""
    def __init__(self, endpoint, consumer_key, consumer_secret):
        super(Restful_Client, self).__init__()
        self.consumer_key = consumer_key
        self.consumer_secret = consumer_secret
        self.endpoint = endpoint

    def make_request(self, resource, params, method='GET' ):
        oauth_params = {
            'oauth_consumer_key': self.consumer_key,
            'oauth_nonce': self.gen_nonce(),
            'oauth_timestamp': self.gen_timestamp(),
            'oauth_signature_method': 'HMAC-SHA1',
            # 'oauth_version':'1.0'
        }
        oauth_params['oauth_signature'] = self.gen_signature(
            resource,
            OrderedDict( params.items() + oauth_params.items() ),
            method
        )
        params = OrderedDict( params.items() + oauth_params.items() )
        clean_params = self.sort_params(self.normalize_params(params))

        uri = endpoint + resource
        p_string = urlencode(clean_params)

        print 'p string:'
        print '\n'.join(p_string.split('&'))

        return httplib2.Http().request(uri + '?' + p_string)

    def gen_signature(self, resource, params, method):
        base_request_uri = quote(self.endpoint + resource, safe = "")
        clean_params = self.sort_params(
            self.normalize_params(
                self.normalize_params(
                    params
                )
            )
        )
        query_string = '%26'.join([
            key + '%3D' + value\
            for key, value in clean_params.iteritems()
        ])
        raw_string = '&'.join([method, base_request_uri, query_string]) 
        print "raw string: "
        print '\n'.join(raw_string.split('%26'))
        hashed = hmac.new(self.consumer_secret, raw_string, sha1)
        return binascii.b2a_base64( hashed.digest() )[:-1]

    def normalize_string(self, string):
        return quote(str(string), safe="")

    def normalize_params(self, params):
        return OrderedDict( [
            (self.normalize_string(key), self.normalize_string(value))\
            for key, value \
            in params.iteritems()
        ])

    def sort_params(self, params):
        return OrderedDict(sorted(
            params.iteritems(),
            cmp=key_compare
        ))

    def gen_timestamp(self):
        return int(time.time())
        # return 1429451603

    def gen_nonce(self):
        return hex(self.gen_timestamp())
        #todo: make this more secure

if __name__ == "__main__":
    store_url = '<STORE URL HERE>'
    api_base = 'wc-api'
    api_ver = 'v2'
    endpoint = "%s/%s/%s/" % (store_url, api_base, api_ver)

    consumer_key = '<CK HERE>'
    consumer_secret = '<CS HERE>'

    resource = 'customers'
    parameters = {
        # 'fields':'id,first_name'
    }

    rc = Restful_Client(endpoint, consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    r, c = rc.make_request(resource, parameters, 'GET')
    print r
    print c
```

What I would suggest is ensuring that the parameters are encoded the correct number of times, I found that the parameters needed to be "double encoded" to work. It looks like in this case your parameters (the key and value strings) are not "double encoded" as suggested in the API doc http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication

You can test this hypothesis by trying a simple GET request without any parameters like the one in my code. if that works then that might be your problem. Good luck!