# WooCommerce orders change page in URL with Python OAuth HTTP request

Tags: python, http, oauth, woocommerce

I would like to fetch orders from WooCommerce with a GET request using an OAuth client from:
[Python OAuth WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452408/python-oauth-woocommerce?lq=1).

My code looks like this:

```
import time
from hashlib import sha1
import hmac
import binascii
from urllib import quote, urlencode
import httplib2
from collections import OrderedDict
import json

def key_compare(a, b):
    return cmp(a[0], b[0])

class Restful_Client(object):
    """docstring for Restful_Client"""
    def __init__(self, endpoint, consumer_key, consumer_secret):
        super(Restful_Client, self).__init__()
        self.consumer_key = consumer_key
        self.consumer_secret = consumer_secret
        self.endpoint = endpoint

    def make_request(self, resource, params, method='GET' ):
        oauth_params = {
            'oauth_consumer_key': self.consumer_key,
            'oauth_nonce': self.gen_nonce(),
            'oauth_timestamp': self.gen_timestamp(),
            'oauth_signature_method': 'HMAC-SHA1',
            # 'oauth_version':'1.0'
        }
        oauth_params['oauth_signature'] = self.gen_signature(
            resource,
            OrderedDict( params.items() + oauth_params.items() ),
            method
        )
        params = OrderedDict( params.items() + oauth_params.items() )
        clean_params = self.sort_params(self.normalize_params(params))
        uri = endpoint + resource
        p_string = urlencode(clean_params)
        return httplib2.Http().request(uri + '?' + p_string)

    def gen_signature(self, resource, params, method):
        base_request_uri = quote(self.endpoint + resource, safe = "")
        clean_params = self.sort_params(
            self.normalize_params(
                self.normalize_params(
                    params
                )
            )
        )
        query_string = '%26'.join([
            key + '%3D' + value\
            for key, value in clean_params.iteritems()
        ])
        raw_string = '&'.join([method, base_request_uri, query_string]) 
        hashed = hmac.new(self.consumer_secret, raw_string, sha1)
        return binascii.b2a_base64( hashed.digest() )[:-1]

    def normalize_string(self, string):
        return quote(str(string), safe="")

    def normalize_params(self, params):
        return OrderedDict( [
            (self.normalize_string(key), self.normalize_string(value))\
            for key, value \
            in params.iteritems()
        ])

    def sort_params(self, params):
        return OrderedDict(sorted(
            params.iteritems(),
            cmp=key_compare
        ))

    def gen_timestamp(self):
        return int(time.time())

    def gen_nonce(self):
        return hex(self.gen_timestamp())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    store_url = '<STORE URL HERE>'
    api_base = 'wc-api'
    api_ver = 'v3'
    endpoint = "%s/%s/%s/" % (store_url, api_base, api_ver)

    consumer_key = '<CK HERE>'
    consumer_secret = '<CS HERE>&' # the & is necessary for api ver v3

    resource = 'orders'
    parameters = {}

    rc = Restful_Client(endpoint, consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    r, c = rc.make_request(resource, parameters, 'GET')
    print json.dumps(r, indent=1)
    c = json.loads(c)
    print json.dumps(c, indent=1)
```

This code results in WooCommerce sending the 10 latest orders which will be stored in the variable c. In the variable r, there are more details about the request stored. This is an example output for the variable r:

```
{
 "status": "200", 
 ...,
 "content-location": "<<STORE URL>/wc-api/v3/orders?oauth_consumer_key=<CK HERE>&oauth_nonce=0x560bc13c&oauth_signature=Ln6IbXciDSNjTfraKe1Cx%252FPRDkU%253D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1443610940", 
 "x-cache": "MISS", 
 "x-wc-total": "1180", 
 ..., 
 "x-wc-totalpages": "118", 
 "-content-encoding": "gzip", 
 "link": "<<STORE URL>/wc-api/v3/orders?oauth_consumer_key=<CK HERE>&oauth_nonce=0x560bc13c&oauth_signature=Ln6IbXciDSNjTfraKe1Cx%2FPRDkU%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1443610940&page=2>; rel=\"next\", <<STORE URL>/wc-api/v3/orders?oauth_consumer_key=<CK HERE>&oauth_nonce=0x560bc13c&oauth_signature=Ln6IbXciDSNjTfraKe1Cx%2FPRDkU%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1443610940&page=118>; rel=\"last\"", 
 ..., 
 "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8", 
 "accept-ranges": "bytes"
}
```

Associated with the key "links", there are the links there are some links on which the request is based, and it is possible to see that the request for orders is sent in different pages. Apparently the above code is always requesting the last page.

**My questions:**

**Where in the code is the requested page specified?**

**How can I specify the page I want to request and if possible change the number of displayed orders per page?**

Every help is greatly appreciated!

(My programming experience is limited.)

Comment: Not sure this will answer your question, but looking at the source code may shed some light: https://github.com/woothemes/wc-api-python/blob/master/woocommerce/api.py

Comment: @Hieu Thanks a lot! It looks like what I needed.